# end to end test should run login setup every time?

Tags: testing, automated-tests, e2e-testing, testcafe, end-to-end

I am testing a platform using testcafe for end to end tests. I have a case for testing login but I have other cases that require login.

I am not sure what is the best option I should run login on every test case setup or should run first a script login and then run all tests? I have tried both and they seem good options.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Having to log in for each and every test is time-consuming and inefficient. I would recommend having a single login for the tests if;

- There is no dependency between the logged in user and the test that is running.
- The actual result you are looking for can be achieved by just a single login

Furthermore, I would use 2-3 users for tests just to be cover multiple users login into the system.

Answer (score 3):

TestCafe has powerful mechanism of [Roles](https://devexpress.github.io/testcafe/documentation/test-api/authentication/user-roles.html) for testing login/logout functionality.
You can create Role for each user account which you would like to test and switch between them in tests. To switch to an unregistered user, you can use `Role.anonymous()`.

The main profit of using Roles is that logging steps are executed only one time during first using of Role and next time TestCafe just reloads the page and restores required credentials.

Answer (score 2):

It depends what you are testing:

1. If you are testing the authentication then they should login each time.
2. If you are testing something else then I would place this in the Arrange part of the code following the [Arrange Act Assert](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh694602.aspx) pattern as it's not relevant to the other tests and as part of the test setup (Arrange) it should navigate back to the home page.
   Ideally you isolate the authentication from other tests for performance, however if your session has some state that it has carried over from the last test you should clean this up so other tests are not effected by it.

   3. [A comment in the Git issue](https://github.com/DevExpress/testcafe/issues/1770) suggests that you can use [preserveUrl](https://devexpress.github.io/testcafe/documentation/test-api/authentication/user-roles.html#optionspreserveurl) to keep your session.